# Should I put outcome variable in Matchit::matchit ()

Tags: r, propensity-scores

I would like to perform a logistic regression by adjusting for propensity score. My question is, do I have to include the outcome (binary in my case) in the propensity score calculation? Otherwise how else can I link the outcome variable to the matched data created? For example if I don't put the outcome variable in function matchit() like in the scripts below

```
library(MatchIt)
m.out<-matchit(treatment~var1+var2+var3+var4, data = data,method = "nearest", ratio=1)
dataMatched = match.data(m.out)
```

I will have such a data.frame which doesn't contain outcome. How could I make the link between the outcome variable and this data frame in order to do the final analysis.

```
 treatment var1 var2 var3 var4 distance weights
1         0    1    1    0    0   0.4135      1
2         0    1    0    1    1   0.5446      1
3         0    0    0    0    0   0.6534      1
4         1    1    1    1    0   0.7343      1


library(Zelig)
z.out = zelig(outcome ~treatment+var1+var2+var3+var4, model = "logit",data = dataMatched )
```

Comment: +1 because this a horrible mistake to make. No, definitely do not use the `outcome` variable for anything else other than evaluating the treatment. Never condition in post-treatment variables. Otherwise would essentially know the future. :)

Comment: after matching with matchit (without the outcome variables), I want to do a test of difference in means to estimate the effect sizes. My problem is the same: How can I combine my mached model with the original dataset for further analysis(test of difference in means). You wrote, the "procedure is a bit more involved". Can you help me? Thanks a lot.
Christoph

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DO NOT include the outcome in the propensity score calculation. To analyze your data after matching, don't use `match.data()`. Just use your original data set, which hopefully contains the treatment and the outcome, and include the weights in the `matchit` output object in the outcome model. You can do this as follows:

```
m.out <- matchit(treatment ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4, data = data,
                 method = "nearest", ratio=1)
fit <- glm(outcome ~ treat, data = data, family = binomial,
           weights = m.out$weights)
```

Observations with weights of zero (indicating that they were not matched) will simply be excluded from the analysis. If you want to do a paired analysis, pair membership is in the `subclass` component of the `matchit` output object and you can include it as a fixed or random effect in the outcome regression model to mimic a paired t-test or use it as the clustering variable in a cluster-robust standard error.

Comment: Hi Noah. I've really learned much from numerous of your answers here.

Doing nearest-neighbour matching currently outputs a subclass variable. Has this just been changed since your posted your answer here, or? 

I want to perform Cox stratified by matched pairs after propensity-score matching (as I understand from the literature that the data have to be treated as paired data).
I assume I can just use something like 
coxph(Surv(time_to, status) ~ exposure + var1 + ... + varN + strata(subclass), data=df))
and that this'll work fine with pool(with()) after using MICE+MatchThem?

Comment: Yes, this has changed since I posted my answer (because of changes I made to `MatchIt`). See the documentation for `MatchThem::with()`. You should not treat the pairs as strata but just account for pairing by treating pair membership as a cluster variable. In `coxph()`, this would be done with the `cluster` argument. If you use `svcoxph()` with `MatchThem`, cluster membership is automatically incorporated.

Comment: Thanks, that’s perfect. After trying stratification by pairs and getting unreasonably wide CIs, I dug through the literature for a bit and arrived at the robust variance estimate-solution as well, and cluster = subclass in copxh() works beautifully. Thanks once again!